# Unable to do pagination with LinkExractor

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to pagination, I've used my method which is working fine but I want to use LinkExtractor function to do the task.

The only problem is problem is that link in a tag is not complete.

```
<a href="/s?k=Winsor+%26+Newton&amp;lo=grid&amp;dc&amp;page=2&amp;qid=1566929157&amp;rnid=1632651031&amp;ref=sr_pg_1">Next<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>→</a>
 rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='Next'), callback='parse', follow=True ),)
```

As you can see the code, how can I add https://www.amazon.co.uk/ in the start of that rule.

Comment: I think that `scrapy` should do this automatically, although I'm not sure whether your `allow` argument is correct? I think it should match the [absolute url not the text of the link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml). It might help if you could post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `allow='Next'`, it doesn’t do what you think it does.

I think you are looking for `restrict_text='Next'` instead.

Check the [LinkExtractor documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml) for a full list of supported parameters.